# Como verificar o tamanho de um objeto javascript (em memória)

Tags: javascript

Como verificar o tamanho de um objeto javascript (em memória) usando javascript puro?

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso em JavaScript. Mas as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chrome incluem [diversos recursos para diagnosticar problemas de memória](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis?hl=en).

Comment: No SOen um rapaz fez a mesma pergunta, de uma lida http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não parece ser possível, no entanto existe uma [biblioteca](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/finding-the-memory-usage-of-objects/) capaz de fazer uma estimativa do tamanho de um objeto.
Depois de adicionada basta usar a função sizeof(). Por exemplo:

```
var tamanho = sizeof(objeto);
```

Comment: Interessante, não conhecia. Dei uma olhada no código, e vi que a biblioteca faz uma conta simples, conforme os tipos dos dados e os tamanhos das chaves dos objetos. Com isso ela dá uma *estimativa* do espaço ocupado. A linguagem não tem suporte a inspeção de memória, portanto o espaço real ocupado é impossível de se obter com ela.